# React router - no default route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using React/Redux/Router but this is really just a router question and one I can't seem to find the answer for. Essentially, I want my app to only kick in if the '#search' hash is present in the URL, otherwise don't do anything.

If I use something like the following I get an error (did not match any routes) when I go to the root URL '/'.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="#search" component={HelloWorldContainer} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('.body-wrap'),
);
```

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

That's because you haven't provided a route for the root `'/'`, which is the default entry point to a web application. I'm not sure why you wouldn't provide a route for the root `'/'` but React Router will continue to throw errors for routes it can't match. You can provide an entire component as a catch-all for routes that don't match what you've specified; like so:

```
<Route path='*' component={ErrorPage}/>
```

Also, a request to the route `path='#search'` must be exact to match. So a request to `/#search123` will throw an error, unless you have the catch-all route above.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm being clear, Keith, or maybe you've misunderstood, but I only want to trigger my app when '#search' is present, otherwise I don't want my app to do anything.

So for example, if you entered the page '/blah' then I just want the server rendered page, however if you went to '/blah#search' you get the browser rendered page with the React component rendered.

Comment: My apologies I think I misunderstood you. You'll probably want to checkout the [React-Router Glossary which covers accessing the query string and pathname](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/Glossary.md).